# Flutter: IconButton() Being Partially Rendered Outside It's Container()

Tags: flutter, layout

I'm trying to up my game when it comes to my Flutter layout / sizing knowledge and this post is something that I recently observed that confuses me.

I have a Container() that has an IconButton() having an icon from the stock Flutter icon set with a size that is passed as a parameter to the function.

Here is the code:

```
  Widget buttonGallery(double size) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.photo,
          size: size,
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
        onPressed: (){}, 
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

With the size set to 75, I am noticing that the IconButton() is being partially rendered outside of its parent Container(). (This behavior is visible as I explicitly set the Container() color to yellow to be able to see the parent client area). See pic below:

[image]

Here are my questions:

- Isn't the parent widget, which in this is a Container(), supposed to envelop it's child widget meaning that the child shouldn't overflow outside of it's parent? (I know that there's the OverflowBox() widget that supposed to allow this behavior, but I don't think that's the case here.)
- In the case where the child is too big to fit its parent's client area, isn't Flutter supposed to clip the child and show those yellow hazzard lines indicating this scenario?
- Having dealt a lot with Container(), I was under the impression that it was supposed to fit itself to the dimensions of its child. I'm confused why it's not doing this now.

All help/suggestions greatly appreciated.

/Joselito

Answer (score 2):

The [IconButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/IconButton-class.html) widget sizes itself according to the property iconSize. It defaults to 24, and that's the size being passed to your container.

This should do it for you:

```
 Widget buttonGallery(double size) {
  return Container(
   color: Colors.yellow,
   child: IconButton(
    iconSize: size,
    icon: Icon(
      Icons.photo,
      size: size,
      color: Colors.blue,
    ),
    onPressed: (){}, 
    },
  ),
 );
}
```

Comment: Edmore, your suggestion to use the IconButton:iconSize property instead of the Icon:size property did the trick! Thank you. And your explanation jives with what was happening, although I did set the Icon:size property at the constructor and it should have returned the new size instead of the default, but hey, I'll take it! Thanks again.